# SELECT AS in Linq with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to populate a drop down list with a Linq query. However, I need to have FirstName and Surname as one field. Concatenating in the `DDL.DataTextField` returns a field not found error.

SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT (FirstName + SPACE + Surname) AS FullName FROM Table WHERE ID=1
```

Current Linq:

```
public IList<mytable> GetNames(int p_ID)
{
    return db.mytable.Where(c => c.ID_fk == p_ID).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this, if you *only* need the full name:

```
public IList<string> GetNames(int p_ID)
{
    return db.mytable.Where(c => c.ID_fk == p_ID)
                     .Select(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.Surname)
                     .ToList();
}
```

Comment: We could use `(from c in db.mytable where c.ID_fk == p_ID select (c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname)).ToList()` too, don't we?

Comment: @Amedio: Yes, I guess that would work too. I prefer the methods syntax in most cases, though. I find it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
return db.mytable.Where(c => c.ID_fk == p_ID).Select(c=>c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname). ToList();
```

so you have a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
return db.mytable.Where(a => a.ID_fk==p_ID)
                  .Select(a => a.FirstName + "-" + a.Surname)
                  .ToList();
```